# PDFBox: Unable to save pdf while running on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, pdfbox

[This PDFBOX Example](https://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/documentcreation.html) when i run from the main method & run java application then it successfully saving pdf document. But if the same code while running from  doGet method of servlet on Tomcat server, then its NOT saving the pdf file. Very confuse can you help me why? do i have to add some external libarary to support for Tomcat server, please help..

Note :

- i have debugged doGet method its getting call not throuwing any
- exception Tomcat 6, PDFBox 1.87, all PDFbox dependecies i have
  included in classpath

  ```
  /* this is the servlet method which is saving pdf file, but the same if run from Main then it saves the "hello world.pdf"*/ 
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        try { 
            PDDocument  document = new PDDocument();
               PDPage page = new PDPage();
               document.addPage( page ); 
               // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
               PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD; 
               // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
               PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page); 
               // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
               contentStream.beginText();
               contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
               contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
               contentStream.drawString( "Hello World1" );
               contentStream.endText(); 
               // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
               contentStream.close(); 
               // Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
               document.save( "Hello World.pdf");

               document.close();

               response.setContentType("text/html"); 
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();   
                out.println("<iframe height=\"100%\"   width=\"100%\" src=\"http://eurecaproject.eu/files/4613/9886/3802/report3.pdf\" ></iframe>");


      } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block

          System.out.println(e);
      }   

  }
  ```

Comment: which environment are you working on? Linux ?

Comment: maybe it isn't saving it in the directory where you're looking? And maybe you didn't look in the tomcat bin directory? Because that is the current directory.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva Windows

Comment: Through your web application, if you point out a location on your drive/folder, will it write there..?

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva Yes it is has both write & read permission on the folder.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i have searched entire in the system with the pdf name but still i don know where it is

Comment: The windows search doesn't really work anymore since Windows 7. To see where the current directory is, do new File("." ).getCanonicalPath(); To create your file at a meaningful place, use an absolute path or use getServletContext().getRealPath("/") and add your filename to this.

Comment: Any solutions? I am having the same issue with Jetty

Answer (score 0):

If you update to the latest version of PDFBox (2.0.0-SNAPSHOT), everything should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code: Sorry I am little bit busy so I can't test your code right now, but I am sure this will help you. Just add few lines while call `doGet()` or `doPost()` just check once what I am using. I spent many hours to find this solution. It will definitely work. If it won't work, please let me know.

I hope that you have already downloaded the pdfbox jar, so then you can import classes by default.

```
//you can use servlet to create pdf 

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")

public class Billing extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

    private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {



            //Create pdf
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

            //Create Page
            PDPage page = new PDPage();

            //Adding the page
            document.addPage(page);


           //Loading the page
           File file = new File("D:/akash/my_doc.pdf");
           //writing text
           contentStream.beginText();
           contentStream.newLineAtOffset(295, 757);
           contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
           contentStream.showText("CHIMERA TRANSPLANT RESEARCH FOUNDATION");
           contentStream.endText();

           //Saving the document
           document.save("D:/akash/my_doc.pdf");


           //Closing the document
            document.close();
   }  
}
```