# PDFbox with Restlet

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, restlet, pdfbox

I am having an issue serving a PDF file from our `Restlet` API.

I am using the basic example code from the [Apache PDFBox documentation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html), it works fine outside of the `Restlet` context.

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

System.err.println("before instantiating new PDPage");
// Create a new blank page and add it to the document
PDPage page = new PDPage(); // LINE FAILING IN RESTLET
System.err.println("after instantiating new PDPage");

document.addPage(page);
document.save("pdf.pdf");
document.close();
```

Here is my attempt to use PDFBox in a resource, ultimately I want to return a `OutputRepresentation` and save the `PDDcoument` to the stream.

The following code stops working at `PDPage page = new PDPage();`, I do not get any exception, the `Restlet` server does not return any response. The text `"after instantiating new PDPage"` is never printed.

**EDIT: I simplified my code as much as I can but I still have the issue**

Here is my basic Router:

```
public class ApiRestletApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/v1/myresource", MyResource.class);
    return router;
  }
}
```

Here is my resource

```
public class MyResource extends ServerResource {

  protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyResource.class);

  @Get
  public Representation toPDF() {

    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    System.err.println("before instantiating new PDPage");
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    System.err.println("after instantiating new PDPage"); //<= never printed
    document.addPage(page);

    return new PDFRepresentation(document);
  }
}
```

here is my web.xml

```
<!-- Restlet application -->
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
  <param-value>com.xxx.api.ApiRestletApplication</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Restlet adapter -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
  </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Catch all requests -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I comment out line with the PDPage declaration and return some `StringRepresentation`, everything works fine. I am able to serve some Json, xml and excel. But this PDF is driving me crazy.

Here is the version I am using:

```
[INFO] +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.crypto:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.2.1:compile

[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun:tools:jar:jdk:system
```

Here is the curl request:

```
curl "http://localhost:8889/v1/myresource" -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" -H "Accept: application/pdf"
```

here is the logs in eclipse:

```
2015-09-21 15:08:15.933:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8889
2015-09-21 15:08:20.698:INFO:/:RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching application: com.xxx.api.ApiRestletApplication@2613622c to URI: 
before instantiating new PDPage
//then nothing
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 2: the following code works, but I still have no clue why my code does not:**

```
public class RestletServerTest extends Application {

  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/v1/myresource", MyResource.class);
    return router;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

    component.getDefaultHost().attach("", new RestletServerTest());
    component.start();
  }
}
```

**EDIT 3: the issue does not seem to be related to Restlet but to PDFBox and servlets: [PDFBox: Unable to save pdf while running on tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548973/pdfbox-unable-to-save-pdf-while-running-on-tomcat)**

**EDIT 4: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/32706385/1039265**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from the PDFBox version. If I use the version `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` (http://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html), I am able to generate a PDF via a servlet. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your sample code and it worked for me.

I've just set up a class PDDocumentRepresentation that wraps a PDDocument:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.representation.OutputRepresentation;

public class PDDocumentRepresentation extends OutputRepresentation {

    private PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

    public PDDocumentRepresentation(PDDocument document) {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        try {
            document.save(outputStream);
            document.close();
        } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the Resource:

```
public class MyResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get
    public Representation getPdf() {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        return new PDDocumentRepresentation(document);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thierry, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I still have the issue. I edited my answer to show the minimum code I used. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please try again with ServerServlet? Everything works fine with a standalone Component but fails when I use ServerServlet.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you never return the content of your created PDF within the response. The returned representation of your annotated method corresponds to the response content.

In your case, it should correspond to a binary one. You could also leverage content disposition header to trigger the download dialog in the browser.

You could try to put this content into a byte array and then send it through Restlet with a dedicated representation (for example the one based on an OuputStream).

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry, it was just for the sake of the example. I edited my question with the code I used to reproduce the problem.